# Unable to parse XML file

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, file-io, xml-parsing

When I try to parse my valid XML file in Java, I get the error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

My XML file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project>
    <moreunimportantstuff></moreunimportantstuff>
</project>
```

This is how I write the file:

```java
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transform;

        try {
            transform = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        transform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transform.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        
        UTF8OutputStreamWriter writer;
        try{
            writer = new UTF8OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(savePath.toString())));
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

        try {
            transform.transform(source, result);
            writer.close();
        } catch (TransformerException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
```

And this is how I try to read it, which produces the error:

```java
Reader reader;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }

        InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
        is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        ArrayList<ImageDataObject> imgList = new ArrayList<>();
        Document doc;

        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

The `UTF8OutputStreamWriter` was added as suggested in another similar question with an identical error, however none of the other suggestions in that thread have helped me.

I have used XML Tools in Notepad++ to validate my XML, and it seems to be valid. There are no characters prior to the first line or the first character (`<`) in that line.

EDIT: Also verified the file exists and is readable from within Java, using the same argument. `file` in the code above is a File object.

EDIT2: Supplying a [sample of the XML file that's failing to parse](https://pastebin.com/gPLDaaae)

Comment: Have you looked at the file with a binary file editor (or hex dump)? Can you post the first (say) 8 bytes of the file? I wonder whether this is a BOM issue...

Comment: I have, just now. Using HxD. "3C 3F 78 6D 6C" which translates directly to "<?xml"

Comment: Hmm. Will attempt to reproduce when I get the chance. (If you could edit your code to be a [mcve] so we can just copy/paste/compile/run, that would make it slightly simpler.)

Comment: I found the issue and I'm confused. After a while of debugging, I found that the file that's being passed has the path `"\\my.xml"` .. When I run `file.exists()` and `file.canRead()`, it returns true on both, and the `FileNotFoundException` isn't thrown.

However, when I change the file so that the path is `"my.xml"`, it parses correctly, even though it points to the same file which I verified. The difference is the "\\" missing.

Comment: Do you have a `my.xml` that's in your root directory? (And are you running on Windows?)

Comment: You seem to be right. It's located in System32 (on Windows). It pointed me there by using Paths.get("temp.wip"). I am thoroughly confused